# How to toggle background image on button click?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have this code:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.detailpressed);
        Chapter_sync.add(chapid);
    }
```

What I am trying to do is toggle all the methods called in the following clicklistener.

Eg first time when I Click this button the setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.detailpressed) is called and on the next click same metod is called with different drawable.

Something like toggle button.
Someone good at this plz help?

Comment: Taking an integer for yes/no type of process and doing each time arithmetic operation is bad idea. You are doing wastage of memory when you take an int for your task and you are doing unnecessary calculation when you are doing i%2. Its so simple to take boolean variable and do some logical stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a variable

```
int i=0;
```

it will increase with every click.

```
if(i%2==0)
   set one image
else 
   set another image
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an array of the drawable's IDs and saving an index:

```
private final int[] myDrawables = {R.drawable.detailpressed, R.drawable.detailpressed1, ...};
//...
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int index = 0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.setBackgroundResource(myDrawables[index++ % myDrawables.length]);
        Chapter_sync.add(chapid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare variable as

```
boolean isOddClicked = true;
```

And update your click listener as

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Do stuff here for chnaging background of button
            if(isOddClicked) {
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.detailpressed);
                isOddClicked = false;
            } else {
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.detailpressed_SECOND_IMAGE);
                isOddClicked = true;
            }

            //Do your task
            Chapter_sync.add(chapid);
        }
```

**NOTE:** If your requirement moves between two images then you can use `toggle button` and customize it. It will work for same as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

#### if xml as the following

```
    <code>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnListView"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_view"
            android:onClick="switchToListView"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGridView"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_view"
            android:onClick="switchToGridView"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    <code>
```

---

#### handling Code will be like

```
<code>
public void switchToListView(View view) {
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGridView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void switchToGridView(View view) {
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGridView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

</code>
```